# How to route audio from device speaker to bluetooth speaker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using `AVPlayer` to play music in my code. I know I can use `MPVolumeView` from `MediaPlayer` to route between speakers, but I am looking for something different(Because I am developing the application in Ionic and I am not able to find some plugin that can perform such thing, plugin which I use is cordova-plugin-media).

I have searched about how to create it and found some answers like I can switch using `AVAudioSession`.
I am not able to find some code related to it so if anyone can help it would be great.

Another thing is that if I change this forcefully how will it behave with Control Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `MPVolumeView` with IONIC as plugin, you just need to control `UITouchUpInside` through code.

Check this if helps.

```
- (void) currentOutputs:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {

    if(!mpVolumeView){
        mpVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        mpVolumeView.showsVolumeSlider = FALSE;
        [self.webView.superview addSubview:mpVolumeView];
        [mpVolumeView setAlpha:0.01];
    }

    UIButton* btn = nil;
    for (UIView *view in [mpVolumeView subviews]){
        if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPButton"]){
            btn = (UIButton*)view;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(btn){
        [btn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

Working plugin

https://github.com/jaymehtasa/cordova-plugin-audioroute

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
do {
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP) 
   } catch _ {

   }
```

[This](http://devmonologue.com/ios/tutorials/avaudiosession-bluetooth-support/) maybe helpful.